# jQuery Autocomplete minLength and Return Values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm implementing autocomplete, but it's firing on the first keypress and it's also returning the value to the textbox, which I don't want as I'm using it as a method to prevent duplicates.

I'm using jQuery 1.6.

Any idea on how to correct this?

```
$("#groupname").autocomplete("resources/getallgroups.php", {
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What autocomplete library are you using? The best one would be jQuery UI in which case you want to change your code to this:

```
$("#groupname").autocomplete({
    source: "resources/getallgroups.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

All the docs are here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I'm using jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Thought this should be a separate answer...

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) `minLength` should be `minChars`. Also I don't see an option for a select callback anywhere but you might be able to use the [result](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler) event like so:

```
$("#groupname").autocomplete("resources/getallgroups.php", {
  minChars: 2
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) { 
  return FALSE;
});
```

Hope that helps